# Using a text file to find and move folders in python

Tags: python

I am new to python but loving it.

I am struggling to get get the final piece of the puzzle.

1. Rename files so they have the same naming convention. done
2. Move files with matching names to a new directory. done
3. Find and move a list of folders, folder names are in a text file. not done

Where I am stuck is I have only managed to only find and move exact file names, which isn't practical or possible.

I need to be able to add 123456, 456456 etc to rows in a text file and return all the folders that start with that string.

This is the part I am stuck on. is glob a better option?

```
folder = []
with open('foldernames.txt') as textfile:
    for row in textfile:
        folder.....
```

==========================================================================
What I have so far.

The starting file names that I have are "a123456_blah_blah.pdf" and "a0123456.zip", they need to be in the same location at the end.

Using the following I am able to create a folder called "123456" and add both files to the folder.

```
import os
import shutil

srcpath = "C:\source"
destpath = "C:\destination"

os.chdir(srcpath)
files = os.listdir(srcpath)

for dpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(srcpath):
    for f in fnames:
        os.chdir(dpath)
        if f.startswith('a'):
            os.rename(f, f.replace('a', '',1))

for dpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(srcpath):
    for f in fnames:
        os.chdir(dpath)
        if f.startswith('0'):
            os.rename(f, f.replace('0', '',1))

for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(srcpath):
        for file in files:
            subFolder = os.path.join(destpath, file[:6])
            if not os.path.isdir(subFolder):
                os.makedirs(subFolder)
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, file), subFolder)
```

this gives me a folder called "123456" that contains "123456.pdf" + "123456.zip".

Comment: where do you want to move the items listed in file? Is it fixed for each one?

Comment: Correct. Same location for each